# Transform similarity to probability

Tags: statistics

i need an idea of a hint to process my works.
What is the problem i currently stuck with.

I have an object A for which i calculated a similarity score in the interval [0;1] by which 1 means identical and 0 non-identical to object(s) based in a vector B, so i get the amount of similarities as many elements the vector B has.

Example:

A -> B1: 0.56
A -> B2: 0.89
A -> B3: 0.34
...

Now i would like to transform this information to a probabilistic approach.
And here i stuck :(
Any idea how to go further here?

Thank you

NB: the amount of links could be up to 100 and more between A->Bn

Comment: What would be a probabilistic approach? Do you want to assign a probability that A is Bi for each specific element of B? If A is equally similar to two elemetns, does that mean that it has equal chance of being both? Can it be both? (For example, a dog is a mammal and a domestic animal). If A can only be a single element of B, maybe $p_i = P(A=B_i) =s_i / \sum{s_i}$ can work ($s_i$ is the i-th similarity).

Comment: Hello.Thanks for coming back. Let us consider we have just 2 elements in B and th same score for A -> B1 and A ->B2. So the probability that A is EITHER B1 OR B2 is the same. And yes you are right: A is linked to just one specific B in reality. So your idea sounds interesting. If someone else has an idea i would be more than happy to read it.